# HelloWorld managed extension example not working on Neo4j 3

Tags: java, neo4j

I've implemented the HelloWorld example extension exactly how it is described here

> http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#server-extending

I've using Neo4j 3.0.2 on my Mac.

I Also tried just compiling the example in the neo4j repo and copying that.

When I try and start the server I see the following message:

> Starting Neo4j failed: Multiple exceptions

The debug log file shows no exception.

I'm uploaded the project with log.txt files and the .neo4j.conf file here https://github.com/whatsthebeef/neo4j-test

**Why isn't it working and is there another place to view these exceptions?**

Comment: can you share the log files?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I've commited the log file to githhub repo because it is big. It's here https://github.com/whatsthebeef/neo4j-test/blob/master/log.txt

Comment: @MichaelHunger I did another reinstall and it's still failing to start but I now see this error - `Starting Neo4j failed: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-38a5b44d@3be393af==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, I just used your repo,

- build it,
- copied the jar to NEO4J_HOME/plugins
- edited the config the same way you did
- restarted Neo4j

Result:

```
curl http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/1

Hello World, nodeId=1
```

Comment: What's your Neo4J home?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that although my neo4j plugin folder was configured to be in one location I actually had to put the plugins in the plugin directory inside the installation `.app` file.

Comment: im encountering the same, could you please elaborate how you solve it. thanks

Comment: If you insist on using the desktop version and not the server version then one way (perhaps not the best) is to cp all plugins and dependencies to the plugin folder inside the app file. In my system it is at /Applications/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins/